# Show elements of where clause that are not present in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I search a table based on an ID column in my where clause. I have a list of IDs that may or may not be present in this table. A simple query will give me the IDs which exist in that table (if any). Is there a way to also return ID's that were not found ?

```
Table --

ID
1GH
2BN
3ER

SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE ID IN (big list 9FG, 1GH, 3UI etc)
--If ID's in above list are not in table, then show those ids.
```

Desired output -

```
9FG, 3UI were not found in the table
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the output you're trying to produce?

Comment: @Mureinik - I updated the question. Let me know if you need more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you need you can do it this way

```
SELECT q.id, 
       CASE WHEN t.id IS NULL THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END id_exists
  FROM
(
  SELECT '9FG' id UNION ALL
  SELECT '1GH' UNION ALL
  SELECT '3UI'
) q LEFT JOIN table1 t
    ON q.id = t.id
```

Output:

```
|  ID | ID_EXISTS |
|-----|-----------|
| 9FG |        no |
| 1GH |       yes |
| 3UI |        no |
```

or if you just need a list of non-existent ids

```
SELECT q.id 
  FROM
(
  SELECT '9FG' id UNION ALL
  SELECT '1GH' UNION ALL
  SELECT '3UI'
) q LEFT JOIN table1 t
    ON q.id = t.id
 WHERE t.id IS NULL
```

Output:

```
|  ID |
|-----|
| 9FG |
| 3UI |
```

The trick is to use an `OUTER JOIN` instead of `WHERE` condition to filter data from your table and be able to see the mismatches.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3f9d/1)** demo

Comment: thanks. the only downside is that I will have to generate a lot of union alls when there are many IDs ie 40-50. Maybe I can use some programming language to generate the SQL for this.

Comment: You can use a (temp) table for passing around lists of ids especially if you do that a lot. Unfortunately table data type and table-valued parameters are available only since SQL Server 2008. On a bright side it's the only way to achieve what you want that I can think of :)

Comment: Thanks again. I will look into that also for later.

Comment: @Trojan.ZBOT Sure. You're quite welcome. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

To search you can use

```
SELECT * 
From Mytable
where id in (
   select id from (values (1), (2), (3)) as SearchedIds(Id) )
```

and the opposite to find unamtched:

```
   SELECT id from (values (1), (2), (3)) as SearchedIds(Id) 
    WHERE id not in (SELECT id From MyTable)
```

The syntax

```
Values(...) asSearchedIds(id)
```

is supported in Sql2008, for Sql2005 you have to do

```
( SELECT 1 as Id UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL ...etc ) as SearchedIds
```

Note: you can rewrite those queries with JOINS (INNER and LEFT)

Comment: That will not work. It will only show IDs that are in table, but not in the where clause. I want it the other way round. Show ID's that are in where clause, but not present in the table.

Comment: "Id in the where clause" , you mean criteria not true ?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe something like:

SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE id NOT IN (val1, val2, val3)

Comment: two errors - Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: That will not work. It will only show IDs that are in table, but not in the where clause. I want it the other way round. Show ID's that are in where clause, but not present in the table.